# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE only inserting, not updating

Tags: mysql, duplicates, insert-update

I have dug through SO questions and none address my specific issue ...  I have read the following relevant threads: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UPDATE+ON+DUPLICATE+KEY+not+inserting), to no avail.

I have a simple table with the following data:

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  id  |  contractor_id  |  section_id  |  page_id  | modified  |  timestamp  |    
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Here is the create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `reusable_page_modified` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contractor_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `section_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13844 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now I have 4 rows in the db right now, and they are (I'll leave off id and timestamp since they are auto generated):

```
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|  contractor_id  |  section_id  |  page_id  |  modified  |
###########################################################
|       1016      |      309     |   10303   |     0      |
|----------------------------------------------------------
|       1017      |      309     |   10303   |     1      |
|----------------------------------------------------------
|       1073      |      309     |   10303   |     1      |
|----------------------------------------------------------
|        240      |      309     |   10303   |     1      |
|----------------------------------------------------------
```

I am focusing on the first line where `modified` is set to `0`.  What I want to do is set it to `1` if `contractor_id`, `section_id` and `page_id` all exist.  If not, enter a new row.

This is what I have:

```
INSERT INTO `reusable_page_modified`
    (contractor_id, section_id, page_id, modified)
    VALUES ('1016', '309', '10303', '1')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `section_id` = '309' 
    AND `page_id` = '10303' 
    AND `contractor_id` = '1016';
```

This creates a new row.  I think I am not understanding the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statment the way it was intended.  I have read the MySQL documentation [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) and still no help.  What am I not seeing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not far from being correct, but your syntax is a bit off.  First, if you want `ON DUPLICATE KEY` to work when a record with duplicate values for the `contractor_id`, `section_id`, and `page_id` columns is inserted, you will need a unique constraint on these three columns.  You can add one using the following:

```
ALTER TABLE reusable_page_modified
ADD CONSTRAINT u_cnst UNIQUE (contractor_id, section_id, page_id);
```

Next, for the actual `INSERT` statement you would use what you have is close, except that you update all the columns which don't require any updating.  Instead, leave the three columns alone and instead update the `modified` column to `1`:

```
INSERT INTO reusable_page_modified
    (contractor_id, section_id, page_id, modified)
VALUES ('1016', '309', '10303', '1')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    modified = 1
```

Comment: I knew I was thinking about it a little differently than intended.  The `modified = 1` makes sense now that I look at it.  Also the constraint makes sense as well ...  Hate getting short sighted when you're staring at something for too long!  Thanks for your input!