# MySQL : INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - Update not working

Tags: mysql, insert, on-duplicate-key

in MySQL **INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE** update not working but insert working fine.

I have tried all possiblities.

my current index is `username` current pk is `id`

here is my query,

```
insert into 
    myDB.auth_tbl 
    (username, `password`, first_name, last_name, email, is_super, is_active, date_joined) 
    values 
    ('me', 'encrypt', 'me', '', 'me@gmail.com', 0, 1, '0000-00-00')
    on duplicate key update `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(id), `username` = 'me';
```

**NOTE:** I have gone through many references and i tried many answers.
one of them are,
I tried [THIS SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377749/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-only-inserting-not-updating) but still not working for me.

am i missed anything ?

Comment: Unique key on username ?

Comment: `id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(id) you can remove that

Comment: Two questions: What error message do you get, if any? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @WalterTross No error it returns 0 rows affected.

Comment: @BerndBuffen yes it is unique and no reaction when i remove id i have tried already..

Comment: and my second question?

Comment: if my pk matches data should update otherwise it should create new record. but update not working. if not matches it creates new record. update alone issue

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `auth_tbl` (
  `id` int(11),
  `username` varchar(32),
  `password` varchar(32),
  `first_name` varchar(32),
  `last_name` varchar(32),
  `email` varchar(32),
  `is_super` int(3) ,
  `is_active` int(3) ,
  `date_joined`  date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY(`username`) 
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


 insert into 
    auth_tbl 
    (username, `password`, first_name, last_name, email, is_super, is_active, date_joined) 
    values 
    ('me', 'encrypt', 'me', '', 'me@gmail.com', 0, 1, '1900-01-01')
    on duplicate key update  `email` = 'me2@gmail.com';



 insert into 
    auth_tbl 
    (username, `password`, first_name, last_name, email, is_super, is_active, date_joined) 
    values 
    ('me', 'encrypt', 'me', '', 'me@gmail.com', 0, 1, '1900-01-01')
    on duplicate key update  `email` = 'me2@gmail.com';
```